# How to append dynamic DOM elements from a directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have an Angular 1.x directive that appends an element. In short:

```ts
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
  template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
  link: function(el) {
    var child = angular.element("<div/>");
    el.append(child);
  }
```

I can migrate this directive to Angular 2 like this:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[mydirective']
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnit() {
    var child = angular.element("<div/>");
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.append(child);
  }
}
```

What's troubling me is this remark in the `nativeElement` official documentation:

> Use this API as the last resource when direct access to DOM is needed.

My question is - how could I properly migrate this directive to Angular 2? My only requirement is to build an element dynamically and append it to the element with the directive.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`Renderer`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) provided by Angular to manipulate the DOM:

```ts
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const child = this.document.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, child);
  }
}
```

This doesn't depend on the native DOM API like `appendChild()`, so in a way it's a platform-independent approach.

Comment: isn't it wrong to create an attribute directive to add/remove elements to DOM? shouldn't we create structural directive instead? I have created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52074619/1822974) on that too

Comment: @DRB, yes, you should use structural directives. I described the approach in the article [Working with DOM in Angular: unexpected consequences and optimization techniques](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866)

Comment: What does`@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document` accomplish?

Comment: Injects `document` in a platform independent way, depending on how the platform defines `document`

Comment: Here's the fixed link for [Working with DOM in Angular: unexpected consequences and optimization techniques](https://indepth.dev/posts/1134/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques).