# How to change border using a structural directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to create an angular directive that does two things.

```
 1. change border of the host element
 2. append a button at the end of the host element
```

As of now i am on the first step where i have to set the border of host element.

**HTML**

```
  <div *myDirective
        <h1> some value </h1>
  </div>
```

**Directive**

```
export class MyDirective{

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
      this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.style['border'] = '1px solid red';
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }      
}
```

Now when i add this directive to a div element,I get the following error,

```
Cannot set property 'border' of undefined
```

How could i change the style and append another element to the host using structural directive?

**[Edit]** 
As most of the answers are suggesting me to create an attribute directive, i just want to post the statement from angular document regarding structural directives.

> They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements.

In that case creating attribute directive to append a button to the host element is not proper. Isn't it?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ElementRef` instead of `TemplateRef`?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yslsmo)

mydirective.ts:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ElementRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMydirective]'
})
export class MydirectiveDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement)
    el.nativeElement.style.border = '2px solid red';
    let bt = document.createElement("button");
    var btContent = document.createTextNode("my Button");
    bt.appendChild(btContent);
    bt.style.cssFloat = 'right'
    this.el.nativeElement.append(bt)
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div appMydirective>
        <h1> some value </h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the border you need to do the following:

Create the directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

// Directive decorator
@Directive({ selector: '[myDirective]' })
// Directive class
export class MyDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    // Use renderer to render the element with styles
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'border', '1px solid red');
    }
}
```

Following you need to declare and export this directive via SharedModule so that the app module can load and import it globally.

Shared.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MyDirective } from './my-directive.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        MyDirective
    ]
})
export class SharedModule{}
```

Then import the shared module in the app.module

then use it as follows:

```
<div myDirective>
    <h1> some value </h1>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ar79y)

Comment: as per angular documentation to add, remove manipulate DOM we need to use structural directive. But what you have created is an attribute directive. Isn't that an anti-pattern?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) an "Attribute directive changes the appearance or behavior of a DOM element". If you want to apply css using a directive it is the way to go and for applying border it is what you are doing. In angular docs they apply a highlight effect which is again a css change so I don't see an anti-pattern.

Comment: as i have the one more requirement where i have to add button at the end of host element, i cannot use attribute directive.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I would use a structural directive for this.

But the templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement is just a html comment, and there is no style property.

To append the button you can follow this very good example of a structural directive:
[Adding a Component to a TemplateRef using a structural Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008451/2410507)